# AngularJS: filter or directive that replace text for a template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I need help to create a custom filter or directive than replace a word for a template. For example, in the text "My product NEW" I would like to replace 'NEW' for the template 'isnew.html'
Any can help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```
<div ng-bind-html="getText()"></div>
```

controller:

```
$scope.getText = function(){
    var new = $templateCache.get('isnew.html');
    return 'My product ' + new;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain bit about your answer ?

Comment: I would provide a plunker lately

Comment: It's works, thank you very much! I have to add this: `app.run(function($templateCache) {
    $http.get('views/common/mylabels/label_new.html').then(function(response){
        $templateCache.put('isnew.html', response.data);
    });
});`